# Cocos2D game tutorials/game suggestions

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I use Ray's link to learn Cocos2D, any other good links or tutorials I can use for developing?

Any suggestions about game developing?

Comment: Who's Ray and where is his link?

Comment: Ray Wenderlich and this is the link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/cocos2d

Answer (score 1):

Since you weren't too specific on what kind of links you wanted...

This is a bit philosophical but helped me stay focused on getting some simple games finished and polished rather than leaving them half done and moving to the next thing:
http://makegames.tumblr.com/post/1136623767/finishing-a-game

Here's a ton of links to all sorts of game related topics:
http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/gameprog.html

For cocos2d I'd suggest grabbing the full source code and opening up the cocos2d-ios workspace  and then compiling and running all the test applications. They'll let you see a bunch of cocos2d's capabilities and give you a starting point to answer those "How would I do X..." type of questions. So after running the TileMapTest you'll know the different type of modes (ortho, iso, etc) it supports and know that there's sample code you look at to get it working.